# Can we use @Query for a SQL operation that gives a result set different from the table structure in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to use @Query in my springboot app, this is effective as long as the result is the same structure as db.

For Example it works fine for the followng example

Employee_Table

```
| empId | Name | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill | 10,000 |
| 2 | Sam | 5000 |
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(Name=Employee_Table)
public class employee() {

@Id
@Column(name="empId");
private String empId;

@Column(name="Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Salary")
private int salary;
}
```

Service:

```
@Query(value = "select * from employee_table where salary>9000",nativeQuery=true)
```

Cause this returns the Employee object which has the same structure as the DB.

But when I try some operation which has something like I want the average of all salaries do I need to follow the same structure using `@Query`? Will the entity class for the operation be like this? What would be a better approach?

```
@Entity
public class employee() {

private int salary;
}
```

I've tried with the `@Query` Annotation but I keep getting the following Exception

> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
> java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: column_name

But when I run the same query on the DB itself I get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `@Query` without whole entities. E.g Something like :

```
@Query(value = "select name, salary from employee where salary>9000")
```

which returns you an `Object[]`.

Or you can define a new class

```
public class SomeEmployeeValues(){
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    public SomeEmployeeValues(String name,  int salary) {
     ...
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

and then you can Query:

```
@Query(value = "select new SomeEmployeeValues(name, salary) from employee where salary>9000")
```

and you get back a `List<SomeEmployeeValues>`

So if you want the avarage of salary you can simply query:

```
@Query(value="select avg(s.salary) from employee s")
```

and you will get back an `List<Object[]>` which contains one element and you can access it like `list.get(0)[0]`.

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to try this. Should the Repository class also be changed from "public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, String> " to "public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Object, String> "?

Comment: @Biswajit No it shouldn't be changed

Comment: Can you share the complete Query?

Comment: Never mind, I am now using the Object[] to fetch my details now.